# Tables: vertical alignment of cell

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I have a `tabu`-table and my default row-style is and **has to be `p`**. But I want the head-row (*Column 1* and *Column 2* in the MWE) to be **vertically** centered. How can I achieve that?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\tabulinesep =0.5em
\newcommand*{\mytext}{\RaggedRight This is some blindtext with words and letters.}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabu} to\textwidth{|X[1,l,p]|X[1,l,p]|X[1,l,p]|}% m is not allowed!!!
    \hline
    Column 1 & Column 2 & Long Long very long caption, more than one line \\
    \hline
    \mytext & \mytext & \mytext \\
    \mytext & \mytext & \mytext \\
    \mytext & \mytext & \mytext \\
    \hline
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: See my edited answer @musicman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, for some reason, changing from `p` type columns to `m` type is not allowed, you can use `\raisebox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\tabulinesep =0.5em
\newcommand*{\mytext}{\RaggedRight This is some blindtext with words and letters.}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabu} to\textwidth{|X[1,l,p]|X[1,l,p]|X[1,l,p]|}
    \hline
    \raisebox{-\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{Column 1} 
      & \raisebox{-\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{Column 2} 
      & Long Long very long caption, more than one line \\
    \hline
    \mytext & \mytext & \mytext \\
    \mytext & \mytext & \mytext \\
    \mytext & \mytext & \mytext \\
    \hline
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @musicman please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you. This is not so bad, but very "manually". I had to recalculate the first raisebox-param everytime the number of lines changes. Any way to automate this?

Comment: @musicman without using "m", I don't know if there's a better way.

Comment: See my edited answer @GonzaloMedina

Comment: @subhamsoni I already did? What's the point on giving the same answer I gave?

Comment: Please see my answer clearly.....

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I will accept your answer, I think there won't come more. I put your code into a more useable command: `\newcommand{\vcorrect}[2][1]{\raisebox{-#1\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{#2}}` So I just have to write `\vcorrect[0.5]{Column1}` for example, if the biggest text has 2 lines.