# Tabular with linespacing

Tags: tables, spacing, longtable

Moin,

I want the rowspacing behavior to be default. So this:

```
\usepackage{longtable}

% ... MAGIC ... %

\begin{longtable}{ccc}
  entry1 & entry2 & entry3 \tabularnewline
  entry4 & entry5 & entry6 \\
  entry7 & entry8 & entry9 \newline
                    foobar
\end{longtable}
```

should produce the same output as this:

```
\usepackage{longtable}

% ... MAGIC ... %

\newlength\myRowSpacing
\myRowSpacing1ex

% ... MAGIC ... %

\begin{longtable}{ccc}
  entry1 & entry2 & entry3 \tabularnewline[\myRowSpacing]
  entry4 & entry5 & entry6 \\[\myRowSpacing]
  entry7 & entry8 & entry9 \newline
                    foobar
\end{longtable}
```

Note how it should not apply to newlines (so multi-line cells have default linespacing).

What I tried:

```
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{\doublespacing}

% ... MAGIC ... %

\begin{longtable}{ccc}
  entry1 & entry2 & entry3 \tabularnewline
  entry4 & entry5 & entry6 \\
  entry7 & entry8 & entry9 \newline
                    foobar
\end{longtable}
```

This produces something I like. Might be even better than the fixed spacing solution, if I figure out a nice factor... **Except that it also applies to newlines** - and I haven't succeeded in redefining newlines (yet).

So, what hack have I missed?

Regards,
  LDericher

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`longtable` obeys `\arraystretch` or (with `array` package) `\extrarowheight` so if you want a spaced out longtable define

```
 \renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
 \begin{longtable}{...}
```

Comment: This is exactly what google and a bunch more search machines refused to tell me! Are there any conflicts/problems with redefining arraystretch?

Comment: @LDericher I don't mention it in the longtable documentation either, I just looked:-) It is supposed to be implicit in the fact that longtables work like standard tabular.

Comment: I didn't know that property at all, yet. So no implicitness for me, I guess ;)

Comment: @LDericher as for redefining `\arraystretch`: that's its only purpose so you can define it to stretch arrays, the only compatibility issue is that it applies to any nested tabular environments so if you have a longtable cell  that contains a tabular and you don't want that to stretch then you will need `...&\renewcommand\arraystretch{1}\begin{tabular}...` to locally put it back inside the cell.

Answer (score 0):

`\newline` has to be used in paragraph cells `p`. Also see [How to add a forced line break inside a table cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2441/how-to-add-a-forced-line-break-inside-a-table-cell) for that topic.

Using `\doublespacing` will also affect such paragraphs inside your table. So you better declare an own command `\newcommand*\nl{\\[3ex]}` and use it at the end of the line.

Maybe your try some other packages, like `tabu` which easily allows *horizontal* aligning in its tables. For *vertical* aligning maybe see my own question [Tables: vertical alignment of cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173810/tables-vertical-alignment-of-cell)

PS. next time consider to put all of your 3 code examples in one compilable MWE.

Comment: I actually used `p` cells, but I built my examples to fit, when I missed that aspect. And I also forgot to mention I don't really like using an own command for that purpose if possible.